# Please explain how to create a table of signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, rational-functions

Given a function: 
$$\begin{align}
\ f(x)& = {\frac{x-1}{(9-x^2)}≥0}, \\
\end{align}$$

how would I go about setting up a table of signs for this function?

Comment: What is the zero of the numerator? When is the numerator positive and when negative? What are the zeros of the denom? On which intervals is the denom positive and negative? Use numberlines for this and divide the signs on the numberlines to establish your answer.           For example, your numerator would look like ------------0+++++++++++

Comment: @Amzoti It's a precalc student :) The teacher may want to see some work of how to get the answer.

Comment: Ok, so the roots would be.
x-1 = 1 (First Root)......
x-3 = 3 (Second Root)......
x+3 = -3 (Third Root)......

Comment: always put the roots in order from small to large

Answer (score 2):

The numerator of your function satisfy

$$x-1 = \left\{\begin{array}{c}\text{positive} & x>1 \\ \text{zero} & x=1 \\\text{negative} & x < 1\end{array}\right.$$

The denominator can be written $9-x^2 = (3-x)(3+x)$. Do the same things as above with the two factors $3-x$ and $3+x$ and then use this to draw the table of signs for the three factors. This will give you something like:

...............-3.......................1..............................3...............

-----------------------------0++++++++++++++++++++ $\text{ for } (x-1)$

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++0---------- $\text{ for } (3-x)$

-----------0+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ $\text{ for } (3+x)$

Now try to combine the three factors above to make the table for $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{(3-x)(3+x)}$.

Comment: That's the method I would endorse. Plain and simple and works for higher end problems too. +1

Answer (score 0):

first you should find root of this function and then you can two optional number one of them one side of root and another,another side of root and obtain its sign.
for example in your sample root is 1 and i give 0 , 2 to function f(0)<0 and f(2)>0
now that in simple root function sign change and if we have two (or even) same root sign of function not change.
(sorry for my bad english)